# What are the ways to say "goodbye" to people in the chat?

Tags: phrase-usage

What are the ways to say "goodbye" to people in a chat room?

I know some:

> - I see you late.
> - Bye.

But, I don't know which them are appropriate or choose.

Comment: That depends on your locale and scene, but generally, synonyms are very easy to find. BTW the first valediction should be **I will see you later**, unless that was meant to be a night date ;)

Comment: In any case, it's: I'll see you later is used for I will see you later.  if you want the pronoun and verb. Using contractions is important.

Comment: While *bye* may simply mean 'see you later,' **good bye,** as I have heard, is a little bit harsh and may mean that I never want to see you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly in British English, "See you later" and "Bye" are common informal ways of saying goodbye after talking.

"I will see you later" is not chatty and wouldn't be a natural thing to say.

"Bye" is a little more formal, better suited to use when you don't know the person very well and/or you know you probably won't be seeing them again any time soon.

"See you later" is probably too informal for someone who would expect to be treated with respect. I wouldn't tell elderly relatives or my boss that I will "see them later".

There are also multiple alternatives to "See you later" that you will start to use when you know someone well - I tend to use phrases like "Catch you later" and "Laters" (which probably says more about my age and the region I grew up in than anything else).